# How can I upload pictures in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, upload, image

I want to create a page where I can upload pictures and at the same time bring them to the page.

for example: I have a picture controller which has Index, addpictures in View.

Could anyone please help me?

I am a beginner, so it would be great if you'd write as simple as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for a tutorial about uploading files in ASP.NET MVC.

The [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class is defined in the System.IO namespace so you will have to bring that into scope.

If you want to be able to show the uploaded file you will have to store it in some other folder than the App_Data. Files are not directly accessible by clients from this folder. You could for example use the Content folder instead. Once you get the file appear in this folder on the server you could reference it from the view using the `<img>` tag: `<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/someimage.jpg")" /`> where you could pass the name of the file to the view from the upload action.

Comment: To display the picture, we should write the <img> tag code always by ourself.
is there any possibilites to display it automatically when ever we upload a picture?

Comment: @user1076915, what do you mean by automatically? In order to display a picture in a web page you use either the `<img>` tag or embed it in the CSS but in your case an img tag is more suitable.

Comment: I thought like an table or database.. you create a new data and it updates the database.. 
I wanna build a page where you can add pictures. the pictures will be shown one after another. the latest photo or the oldest photo is at the top. Did you get it? thanks mate..

Comment: @user1076915, yes, many possibilities exist. You could store the file inside a database and then write a special controller action that will fetch it from the database given its unique id and stream it to the client. But don't expect out-of-the-box solutions. If there is some specific part of the implementation you are having troubles with you could start a new question and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and what difficulties did you encounter.